# RCF of $(x^2+1)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm studying for my qualifying exam. A question asks to find the RCF of each $4 \times 4$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ having minimal polynomial $(x^2+1)^2$.

There is only one option:
$$
R =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
Now we are asked to find the RCF over $\mathbb{C}$. Since the minimal polynomial splits over $\mathbb{C}$, then the RCF is
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -2i \end{bmatrix} $$

Let $A$ and $B$ be the matrices of transition for $R$ and $P$ respectively. Then $ARA^{-1} = R = BPB^{-1}$. It follows that $R = (A^{-1}B)R(A^{-1}B)^{-1}$.

Finally, we must repeat the first two steps for $5 \times 5$ matrices.

Claim: This is impossible over $\mathbb{R}$. For the only possible invariant factors are $(x^2+1)$ and $(x^2+1)^2$. $5 = 4+1$. There is no invariant factor having degree 1, so no such matrix exists.

Since $(x^2+1)^2$ splits over $\mathbb{C}$, then there are possibilities. They are diag$(i,P)$ and diag$(-i,P)$. These last parts are where I am uncertain.

Comment: The answer to the very first part is not just $R$, but all the matrices $P^{-1}RP$, for $P$ invertible.

Comment: Looking at wolfram,  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html, there is only one $6×6$ matrix with that minimal polynomial...

Comment: True. I phrased the question slightly different than was intended so yes, we do want all matrices similar to R. There is no confusion in my mind about that. I edited the post so that this isn’t an issue.